# Looking for a FormBuilder that gives me all images and sourcecode to my form

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql

Wow, I started my search this morning and didn't think it would be so difficult to find. I'm just tired of spending hours putting together simple html forms in dreamweaver. I'm an enthusiast web developer mostly focused on php and mysql. I hate CSS and HTML and I'm looking for a simple program that will put a form together for me where I can then completely embed the form into my site.

I'll do all of the programming to attach it to my database I just need the form and images. I've looked into jotform, wufoo, 123forms etc but it seems like they all want to keep my form on their servers in one way or another. It looked like jotform had a developers version but $450 bucks is a little steep for a part timer like me.

Is there no simple software out there that will throw a nice stylized form together for me?

Comment: The whole point of an web app is that it's not supposed to be hosted on your server. Take a look at [Dreamweaver form building plugins](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?searchfield=form+builder&search_exchange=3&search_category=-1&search_license=&search_rating=&search_platform=0&search_pubdate=&num=25&startnum=1&event=search&sticky=true&sort=0&rnav_dummy_tmpfield=&Submit=).

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at my answer below? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/25852/13311

Comment: If you'll do all the programming why not Google CSS Forms, or CSS3 Forms etc you'll find a lot of really nicely designed forms which you can just add your server side code to.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MachForm](http://www.appnitro.com/machform/features). You buy a license, install on your server and you own it. It's user friendly, it can input data into a database and can also generate sophisticated emails. You don't really need to know much programming at all, their's a very nice GUI to build forms. I used it in my early days of not know much coding at all. It's well worth the price and you own the source once you buy it, nothing is encrypted. The UI is also extremely elegant and uses Ajax. It's easily embeddable into a simple HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.freedback.com/. You can create forms online and copy the codes in your site.